# Why is the %n format specifier working normal for all scanf() statements but storing one less in the first one?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

The `%n` format specifier,when used in a `scanf()` is expected to store the count of the number of characters of the format string already processed by the function into an argument of type `int*`.According to the definition:

`The number of characters of the format string already processed is stored in the pointed location.`

But in my program,it works so in all but the first `scanf()`.In all `scanf()`s in my program,excluding the first one,it stores the count of the total number of characters entered from the console,including the newlines (**Enter** keys).But in the first `scanf()`, the count is  **one less than** the total count of characters and newlines entered from the console.

Please explain this anomaly as it's really frustrating that I can't detect this simple bug.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int a,b,c,d,count;

    printf("First Trial\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%n",&a,&b,&c,&d,&count);  //OUTPUT ANOMALY HERE
    printf("count=%d\n",count);

    printf("Second Trial\n");
    scanf("%d%n",&a,&count);
    printf("count=%d\n",count);

    printf("Third Trial\n");
    scanf("%d%d%n",&a,&b,&count);
    printf("count=%d\n",count);

    printf("Fourth Trial\n");
    scanf("%d%n%d",&a,&count,&b);
    printf("count=%d",count);
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
First Trial
253 
34  
4 
83
count=11

Second Trial
25
count=3

Third Trial
234 
38 
count=7

Fourth Trial 
3534
35
count=5
```

**Why in the first trial we get "11" instead of "12**?That's my doubt.

**CRUCIAL EDIT**

Another finding.If for the first `scanf()`,instead of using `Enter` keys(newlines) to separate the numbers entered, if I use space,lots of whitespace,then all those whitespace are counted by `count` as well.For example I get `count=21`.It means the newlines,spaces,everything is being considered.But why it is **one less** for first trial?

```
First Trial
25    35    38   98
count=21
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> excluding the first one,it stores the count of the total number of characters entered from the console,including the newlines (Enter keys)

You are misinterpreting that. The `scanf`s do *not* consume the final newlines used to send the input to the programme, therefore the newline is left in the buffer to be consumed by the *next* `scanf`. All but the first `scanf` consume the newline from the previous input as the first character.

The first `scanf` consumes the eight digits plus the three newlines between the four numbers, that makes 11 characters.

The second consumes the newline from after the fourth number read in the first `scanf`, plus the two digits, makes 3 characters.

The third: newline, three digits, newline, two digits: 7 characters.

The fourth: newline, four digits: 5 characters. (then newline + 2 digits for `b`)

By the way, your quote

> The number of characters of the format string already processed is stored in the pointed location.

is incorrect, it's not the number of characters of the format string, but the number of characters read from the input stream:

> The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   signed integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from
>   the input stream so far by this call to the fscanf function.

Comment: If the first `scanf()` doesn't consume newlines used to sent the input,then how would you explain the count **11**?Nothing else describes that as the total count of characters is 8 (The digits of all the numbers for first scanf() combined)

Comment: Nothing else describes the counts in other `scanf()`s as well if we assume newlines are not being consumed.

Comment: Actually that line is taken from the Cplusplusreference.But I knew what it meant even though it was written the wrong way....I knew it meant the characters read from the input stream.

Comment: Anyways,how would you explain the count of **11** for the first `scanf()` if newlines are not consumed?

Comment: `11="253\n34\n4\n83"` `3="\n25"` `7="\n234\n38"` `5="\n3534"` Is this correct?

Comment: @Thokchom Clarified, `scanf` doesn't consume the final newline, entered after the last input to be converted, the newlines between the numbers are consumed.

Comment: @DanielFischer Please check my edit.If I use spaces instead of newlines to separate the inputs,then ALL spaces are counted as well.So it's obvious newlines used to send the input to the program are counted as well.

Comment: @Thokchom The spaces between the numbers are counted as well, of course. No whitespace after the last conversion before the `%n` is counted. It's not entirely clear what precise input you sent, copying the line `25    35    38   98`, I get the output `count=19` as expected.

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually you are right about `count=19`.I added some more spaces when I entered from the console but in my question,randomly added spaces.Anyways,I understand now what was wrong.And yes,I had expected downvotes as I felt the question was too trivial!!!

Comment: @Thokchom I guess that was one expectation you don't mind at all to have been wrong (so far, at least) ;) It's not a terribly deep question, but it's well enough phrased, includes all necessary data, so I don't see a reason for a downvote.